# Sonar Maven HTTP error: 401

Tags: maven, http, sonarqube, http-status-code-401

Need some help. Currently writing custom rules for my company. But during testing I encountered a problem. When I start local sonar and try to run project on it to test new rules, I get BUILD FAILURE. This is what I see when running project:

```
C:\Users\tgriusys\eclipse-workspace\simpleProject>mvn sonar:sonar
14:37:12:900 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
14:37:13:353 [INFO]
14:37:13:353 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:37:13:353 [INFO] Building simpleProject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
14:37:13:353 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:37:13:451 [INFO]
14:37:13:451 [INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) @ simpleProject ---
14:37:13:815 [INFO] User cache: C:\Users\tgriusys\.sonar\cache
14:37:13:897 [INFO] SonarQube version: 6.7.1
14:37:13:916 [INFO] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-    1257" (analysis is platform dependent)
14:37:14:178 [INFO] Publish mode
14:37:14:317 [INFO] Load global settings
14:37:14:388 [INFO] Load global settings (done) | time=72ms
14:37:14:396 [INFO] Server id: AWDU5v5flIPWulLSdQv7
14:37:14:405 [INFO] User cache: C:\Users\tgriusys\.sonar\cache
14:37:14:682 [INFO] Load plugins index
14:37:14:736 [INFO] Load plugins index (done) | time=54ms
14:37:15:313 [INFO] Process project properties
14:37:15:383 [INFO] Load project repositories
14:37:15:917 [INFO] Load project repositories (done) | time=534ms
14:37:16:027 [INFO] Load quality profiles
14:37:16:267 [INFO] Load quality profiles (done) | time=240ms
14:37:16:287 [INFO] Load active rules
14:37:16:498 [INFO] Load active rules (done) | time=211ms
14:37:16:502 [INFO] Load metrics repository
14:37:16:526 [INFO] Load metrics repository (done) | time=25ms
14:37:16:539 [INFO] Project key: simpleProject:simpleProject
14:37:16:540 [INFO] -------------  Scan simpleProject
14:37:16:641 [INFO] Base dir: C:\Users\tgriusys\eclipse-workspace\simpleProject
14:37:16:641 [INFO] Working dir: C:\Users\tgriusys\eclipse-workspace\simpleProject\target\sonar
14:37:16:644 [INFO] Source paths: pom.xml, src/main/java
14:37:16:644 [INFO] Test paths: src/test/java
14:37:16:645 [INFO] Source encoding: windows-1257, default locale: en_US
14:37:16:679 [INFO] Load server rules
14:37:16:798 [INFO] Load server rules (done) | time=119ms
14:37:16:905 [INFO] Index files
14:37:16:922 [INFO] 7 files indexed
14:37:16:923 [INFO] Quality profile for java: Exigen Coverage
14:37:16:924 [INFO] Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
14:37:17:054 [INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java]
14:37:17:189 [INFO] Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 5
14:37:17:222 [INFO] JavaClasspath initialization
14:37:17:238 [INFO] JavaClasspath initialization (done) | time=16ms
14:37:17:239 [INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization
14:37:17:242 [INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization (done) | time=3ms
14:37:17:508 [INFO] Java Main Files AST scan
14:37:17:509 [INFO] 6 source files to be analyzed
14:37:17:948 [INFO] Java Main Files AST scan (done) | time=439ms
14:37:17:948 [INFO] 6/6 source files have been analyzed
14:37:17:948 [INFO] Java Test Files AST scan
14:37:17:949 [INFO] 0 source files to be analyzed
14:37:17:950 [INFO] Java Test Files AST scan (done) | time=2ms
14:37:17:950 [INFO] 0/0 source files have been analyzed
14:37:17:951 [INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java] (done) | time=897ms
14:37:17:952 [INFO] Sensor FindBugs Sensor [findbugs]
14:37:19:188 [INFO] Loading findbugs plugin: C:\Users\tgriusys\eclipse-workspace\simpleProject\target\sonar\findbugs\findsecbugs-plugin.jar
14:37:19:207 [INFO] Findbugs output report: C:\Users\tgriusys\eclipse-workspace\simpleProject\target\sonar\findbugs-result.xml
14:37:20:931 [INFO] Sensor FindBugs Sensor [findbugs] (done) | time=2979ms
14:37:20:932 [INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java]
14:37:20:933 [INFO] parsing [C:\Users\tgriusys\eclipse-workspace\simpleProject\target\surefire-reports]
14:37:20:935 [INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java] (done) | time=3ms
14:37:20:935 [INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java]
14:37:20:938 [INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java] (done) | time=3ms
14:37:20:938 [INFO] Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
14:37:20:950 [INFO] 1 source files to be analyzed
14:37:21:577 [INFO] Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=639ms
14:37:21:578 [INFO] 1/1 source files have been analyzed
14:37:21:578 [INFO] Sensor XML Sensor [xml]
14:37:21:719 [INFO] Sensor XML Sensor [xml] (done) | time=141ms
14:37:21:719 [INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
14:37:21:737 [INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=18ms
14:37:21:738 [INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer
14:37:21:757 [INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=19ms
14:37:21:758 [INFO] SCM Publisher is disabled
14:37:21:759 [INFO] 6 files had no CPD blocks
14:37:21:759 [INFO] Calculating CPD for 0 files
14:37:21:760 [INFO] CPD calculation finished
14:37:21:889 [INFO] Analysis report generated in 112ms, dir size=19 KB
14:37:21:931 [INFO] Analysis reports compressed in 41ms, zip size=15 KB
14:37:21:956 [INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 24ms
14:37:21:957 [INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/simpleProject:simpleProject
14:37:21:958 [INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
14:37:21:959 [INFO] More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AWOCfVUd_KYAMsLyvlL2
14:37:21:962 [INFO] Executing post-job org.sonar.report.pdf.batch.PDFPostJob
14:37:21:963 [INFO] Executing decorator: PDF Report
14:37:21:972 [INFO] Team workbook report type selected
14:37:22:058 [INFO] Retrieving project info for simpleProject:simpleProject
14:37:22:234 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:37:22:234 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
14:37:22:235 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:37:22:236 [INFO] Total time: 9.616 s
14:37:22:237 [INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-21T14:37:22+03:00
14:37:22:369 [INFO] Final Memory: 27M/981M
14:37:22:369 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:37:22:373 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project simpleProject: HTTP error: 401, msg: , query: org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod@5d957cf0 -> [Help 1]
14:37:22:374 [ERROR]
14:37:22:375 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
14:37:22:375 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
14:37:22:376 [ERROR]
14:37:22:376 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
14:37:22:377 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

After this I can check analysis and check if rules are working properly but I wonder why build fails and what can I do to solve it?

Comment: It looks like your authentication to your sonar server does not work based on that: `HTTP error: 401, msg: , query: or...`

Comment: @khmarbaise  what do you mean?

Comment: Error 401 means that you're not authorized to analyze this project. It means that either this project requires specific authorization and you're missing the "sonar.login" and "sonar.password" parameters, or the credentials you've used has no access on the project

Comment: but if I am missing something does project would be analysed successfully? I tried to check my permissions in administration tab, I tried to run analysis with login and password properties but error stays

Answer (score 0):

In my situation,it`s the pdf report plugin that caused the BUILD FAILURE error.
After the plugin is removed in the sonarqube web and server dir ,then the analysis goes well.

Here is the part of error message:

```
An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.8.0.2131:sonar: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.api.batch.postjob.PostJobContext.settings()Lorg/sonar/api/config/Settings;
```

Comment: Please don't post images when you can post text - see [answer].